# How to set the cache expiry period of a whole folder of jpgs using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, caching

How can I set the cache expiry date of a whole folder of images using .htaccess?

Right now, I only want the contents of one specific folder to be given a long cache expiry date.  I'm currently using the following code (pasted below), but I find it a pain because every time I add a new piece of art, I have to add it to this list.  Is there a way I can just specify the entire folder?

```
<FilesMatch" (\.css|main_banner.jpg|cart.png|main_logo.jpg|favicon.ico|search_button.jpg|fp_banner.jpg)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just put the .htaccess file in that folder.  Then all you need is the `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"` directive, without worrying about the `FilesMatch` condition.

Comment: While I'm not sure how to test this, It makes sense to me :)